# PHPで複数のエラーが表示

Tags: php

PHPで自動販売機システムを作成しているのですが、
開くといきなりNotice: Undefined variableエラーと何も入力されていないのにエラーメッセージが表示されたり、
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

空欄で入力すると、別の変数のNotice: Undefined variableエラーが表示され、不要なエラーメッセージまで表示されます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

バリデーション関数を作成したり、return文でうまくやりくりしたつもりでした。
returnの箇所が悪いのでしょうか。
お手数をおかけしますが、考え方をご教授のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

functions.php

```
<?php
require_once('../../include/conf/const.php');
require_once('../../htdocs/mvc/tool.php');
require_once('../../htdocs/mvc/index.php');
require_once('../../htdocs/mvc/result.php');


function get_db_connect() {
 
if (!$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWD, DB_NAME)) {
        die('error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    mysqli_set_charset($link, DB_CHARACTER_SET);
    return $link;
}

function close_db_connect($link) {

    mysqli_close($link);
}

function insert_drink($link) {
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
    return;
}
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_POST['sql_kind'] === 'insert') {
        
        if (isset($_POST['new_name']) === TRUE) {
            
            $new_name = $_POST['new_name'];
                
        }
        
        if (isset($_POST['new_price']) === TRUE) {
        
            $new_price = $_POST['new_price'];
                    
        }
        
        if (isset($_POST['new_stock']) === TRUE) {
            
            $new_stock = $_POST['new_stock'];
                
            
        }
        
        if ($_FILES['new_img']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            
            
                /* $chk_pictureにgetimagesize($_FILES['new_img']['tmp_name'])を代入する。*/
                $chk_picture = getimagesize($_FILES['new_img']['name']);
                
                /*もしも$chk_picture['mine]に'image/png'が入っているまたは、$chk_picture['mine]に'image/jpeg'が入っているならば、*/
                if ($chk_picture['mime'] === 'image/png' || $chk_picture['mime'] === 'image/jpeg') {
                    
                    /*もしも$chk_picture[0]が500以下かつ、$chk_picture[1]が500以下ならば、*/
                    if ($chk_picture[0] <= 500 && ($chk_picture[1] <= 500)) {
                        
                        /*$mineに$chk_picture['mime']を代入。*/
                        $mime = $chk_picture['mime'];
                        
                        /*$mineの時*/
                        switch ($mime) {
                            /*'image/png'ならば*/
                            case 'image/png':
                                
                                /*$typeに'.png'を代入。*/
                                $type = '.png';
                                
                                /*breakで処理中断。*/
                                break;
                            
                            /*'image/ipeg'ならば*/
                            case 'image/jpeg':
                                
                                /*$typeに'.jng'を代入。*/
                                $type = '.jpg';
                                
                                 /*breakで処理中断。*/
                                break;
                        }
                        $uploaddir = './drink_picture/';
                        $upload = $uploaddir . date('YmdHis') . rand(0, 10000) . $type;
                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['new_img']['tmp_name'], $upload);
                        var_dump($chk_picture);
                      /*違うならば*/
                    } else {
                        /*配列$err_msgの中に'ファイルは縦と横500px以内にしてください'を入れる。*/
                        $err_msg[] = 'ファイルは縦と横500px以内にしてください';
                    }
                /*違うならば*/
                } else {
                    /*配列$err_msgの中に'PNGかJPEG形式のファイルをアップロードしてください'を入れる。*/
                    $err_msg[] = 'PNGかJPEG形式のファイルをアップロードしてください';
                }
            }
          /*違うならば*/
        } else {
            /*配列$err_msgの中に'ファイルを選択してください'を入れる。*/
            $err_msg[] = 'ファイルを選択してください';
        }

        /*もしもisset($_POST['new_status']の中身がTRUEならば*/
        if (isset($_POST['new_status']) === TRUE) {
            
            /*もしもisset($_POST['new_stock']の中身がTRUEならば*/
            if ((int) $_POST['new_status'] === 0 || (int) $_POST['new_status'] === 1) {
                $new_status = (int) $_POST['new_status'];
            } else {
                $err_msg[] = 'ステータスは公開か非公開を選択してください';
                
            }
        } else {
            $err_msg[] = 'ステータスを選択してください';
            
        }


            $new_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

            $insert_data_info = [
                'drink_name' => $new_name,
                'price' => $new_price,
                'created_at' => $new_time,
                'updated_at' => $new_time,
                'status' => $new_status,
                'path' => $upload
            ];

            $sql = 'INSERT INTO drink_info_table(drink_name, price, created_at, updated_at, status, path) VALUES(\''.$new_name.'\',\''.$new_price.'\',\''.$new_time.'\',\''.$new_time.'\',\''.$new_status.'\',\''.$upload.'\')';

            if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) === TRUE) {

                $drink_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);

                $insert_data_stock = [
                    'drink_id' => $drink_id,
                    'stock' => $new_stock,
                    'created_at' => $new_time,
                    'updated_at' => $new_time
                ];

                $sql = 'INSERT INTO stock_table(drink_id, stock, created_at, updated_at) VALUES(\''.$drink_id.'\',\''.$new_stock.'\',\''.$new_time.'\',\''.$new_time.'\')';

                if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) !== TRUE) {
                    $err_msg[] = 'stock_tableへのデータの登録に失敗しました';
                    
            
                }
            } else {
                $err_msg[] = 'drink_info_tableへのデータの登録に失敗しました';
                
                
            }
                $complete_msg[] = '追加登録完了!';
                
            }


        
function update_drink() {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_POST['sql_kind'] === 'update') {

        if (isset($_POST['update_stock']) === TRUE) {
            if (preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', cut($_POST['update_stock'])) === 1) {
                $update_stock = (int) cut($_POST['update_stock']);

                $update_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                $update_id = $_POST['drink_id'];

                $sql = 'UPDATE stock_table SET stock = ' . $update_stock . ', updated_at = \'' . $update_time . '\' WHERE drink_id = ' . $update_id;

                if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) === TRUE) {
                    $complete_msg[] = '在庫数更新完了!';
                    
                    ;
                    
                } else {
                    $err_msg[] = '在庫数の更新に失敗しました';
                    
                   
                }
            } else {
                $err_msg[] = '0以上の半角整数を入力してください';
                
              
            }
        }
    }
}
function change_drink() {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_POST['sql_kind'] === 'change') {

        if (isset($_POST['change_status']) === TRUE) {
            if ((int) $_POST['change_status'] === 0 || (int) $_POST['change_status'] === 1) {
                $change_id = $_POST['drink_id'];
                $change_status = (int) $_POST['change_status'];

                $change_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                $sql = 'UPDATE drink_info_table SET updated_at = \'' . $change_time . '\', status = ' . $change_status . ' WHERE drink_id = ' . $change_id;


                if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) === TRUE) {
                    $complete_msg[] = 'ステータス変更完了!';
                    
                } else {
                    $err_msg[] = 'ステータスの変更に失敗しました';
                }
            } else {
                $err_msg[] = 'ステータスは公開か非公開を選択してください';
            }
        }
    }

    if (count($err_msg) === 0) {
        
        mysqli_commit($link);
    } else {
        
        mysqli_rollback($link);
    }

    $sql = 'SELECT drink_info_table.drink_id, drink_info_table.drink_name, drink_info_table.price, stock_table.stock, drink_info_table.status, drink_info_table.path FROM drink_info_table LEFT JOIN stock_table ON drink_info_table.drink_id = stock_table.drink_id';
    
    if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    } else {
        $err_msg[] = 'データの抽出に失敗しました';
    }
}



function do_sql($link) {
    $sql = 'SELECT drink_info_table.drink_id, drink_info_table.drink_name, drink_info_table.price, drink_info_table.path, drink_info_table.status,stock_table.stock
    FROM drink_info_table
    JOIN stock_table
    ON drink_info_table.drink_id = stock_table.drink_id';
    $data = [];
    if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    } else {
        $err_msg[] = 'データの抽出に失敗しました';
    }
    return $data;
}

function id_check() {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

        $purchase_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        if (isset($_POST['drink_id']) === TRUE) {

            switch (TRUE) {
                case ($_POST['drink_id'] === ''):
                    $err_msg[] = 'index.phpからdrink_idを受信できませんでした';
                    break;
                case ($_POST['drink_id'] === NULL):
                    $err_msg[] = 'index.phpからdrink_idを受信できませんでした';
                    break;
                default:
                    $drink_id = (int) $_POST['drink_id'];
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            $err_msg[] = '商品を選択してください';
        }

        if (isset($_POST['money']) === TRUE) {

            switch (TRUE) {
                case ($_POST['money'] === ''):
                    $err_msg[] = '金額を入力してください';
                    
                    break;
                case ($_POST['money'] === NULL):
                    $err_msg[] = 'index.phpからmoneyを受信できませんでした';
                    
                    break;
                case (preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', cut($_POST['money'])) !== 1):
                    $err_msg[] = '金額は0以上の半角整数を入力してください';
                    
                    break;
                default:
                    $money = (int) cut($_POST['money']);
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (count($err_msg) === 0) {

            $sql = 'SELECT drink_info_table.drink_name, drink_info_table.price, drink_info_table.path, drink_info_table.status, stock_table.stock
            FROM drink_info_table
            JOIN stock_table
            ON drink_info_table.drink_id = stock_table.drink_id
            WHERE drink_info_table.drink_id = ' . $drink_id;

            if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $data[] = $row;
                }
            } else {
                $err_msg[] = '情報の取得に失敗しました';
            }

            foreach ($data as $info) {

                $drink_name = $info['drink_name'];
                $price = (int) $info['price'];
                $stock = (int) $info['stock'];
                $path = $info['path'];
                $status = (int) $info['status'];

                $remaining_stock = $stock - 1;
                $return = $money - $price;
            }

            switch (TRUE) {
                case ($return < 0):
                    $err_msg[] = 'お金が足りません';
                    
                    break;
                case ($remaining_stock < 0):
                    $err_msg[] = 'この商品は品切れです';
                    
                    break;
                case ($status === 0):
                    $err_msg[] = 'この商品は選択できません';
                    
                    break;
            }

            $sql = 'UPDATE stock_table SET stock = ' . $remaining_stock . ', updated_at = \'' . $purchase_time . '\' WHERE drink_id = ' . $drink_id;

            if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {

                $sql = 'INSERT INTO drink_history_table(drink_id, purchased_at) VALUES (' . $drink_id . ', \'' . $purchase_time . '\')';

                if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) !== TRUE) {
                    $err_msg[] = 'drink_history_tableへの追加に失敗しました';
                    
                }
            } else {
                $err_msg[] = 'stock_tableの更新に失敗しました';
        }
        
    }
}

function html_enc($text){ 
return htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
}

function validation_check($link) {
if (isset($_POST)) {
    if ($_POST['new_name'] === "") {
     $err_msg[] = '商品名を入力してください。';
    }
    
    if ($_POST['new_price'] === "") {
     $err_msg[] = '値段を入力してください';
    }
    
    if (preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $_POST['new_price']) !== 1) {
     $err_msg[] = '値段は0以上の半角整数を入力してください';
    }
    
    if ($_POST['new_stock'] === "") {
     $err_msg[] = '個数を入力してください';
    }
    
    if (preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $_POST['new_stock']) !== 1) {
     $err_msg[] = '在庫は0以上の半角整数を入力してください';
    }
    return $err_msg;
    
}

}
```

tool.php

```
<?php
require_once('../../include/model/functions.php');
require_once('../../include/conf/const.php');
$link = get_db_connect();
$data = insert_drink($link);
$data = do_sql($link);
require_once('../../include/view/tool2.php');

$data =  [
                'drink_name' => '',
                'price' => '',
                'created_at' => '',
                'updated_at' => '',
                'status' => '',
                'path'  => ''
            ];

close_db_connect($link);
```

tool2.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>自動販売機商品管理</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php $complete_msg = insert_drink($link);
    if (count($complete_msg) !== 0) {
        foreach ($complete_msg as $complete) { ?>
            <p><?php print $complete; ?></p>
    <?php }
    } ?>
    <?php $err_msg = validation_check($link);
    if (count($err_msg) !== 0)  {
        foreach ($err_msg as $err) { ?>
            <p><?php print $err; ?></p>
    <?php }
    } ?>

    <h1>自動販売機管理ツール</h1>

    <section>
        <h2>新規商品追加</h2>

        <form action="tool.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label>名前: <input type="text" name="new_name" size="30" /></label><br>
            <label>値段: <input type="text" name="new_price" size="30" /></label><br>
            <label>個数: <input type="text" name="new_stock" size="30" /></label><br>
            <input type="file" name="new_img" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif" /><br>
            <select name="new_status"><br>
                <option value="0">非公開</option>
                <option value="1">公開</option>
                <option value="2">入力チェック用</option>
            </select><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="insert">
            <input type="submit" value="■□■□商品追加■□■□" />
        </form>

    </section>

    <section>
        <h2>商品情報変更</h2>
        <table>
            <caption>商品一覧</caption>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>商品画像</th>
                    <th>商品名</th>
                    <th>価格</th>
                    <th>在庫数</th>
                    <th>ステータス</th>
                </tr>

                <?php if (empty($data) !== TRUE) {
                    foreach ($data as $list) {
                        if ((int) $list['status'] === 0) { ?>
                            <tr class="status_0">
                            <?php } else { ?>
                            <tr>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <td><img class="image" src="<?PHP print $list['path']; ?>"></td>
                            <? php print htmlspecialchars($list,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'); ?>
                            <td class="d_name"><?php print $list['drink_name']; ?></td>
                            <td class="d_price"><?php print $list['price']; ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <form method="post">
                                    <input type="text" class="input_text_width text_align_right" name="update_stock" value="<?php print $list['stock']; ?>">個
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="submit" value="変更">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="drink_id" value="<?php print $list['drink_id']; ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="update">
                                </form>
                            </td>

                            <?php if ((int) $list['status'] === 0) { ?>
                                <td class="d_status">
                                    <form method="post">
                                        <input type="submit" value="非公開 → 公開">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="change_status" value="1">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="drink_id" value="<?php print $list['drink_id']; ?>">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="change">
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <td class="d_status">
                                <form method="post">
                                    <input type="submit" value="公開 → 非公開">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="change_status" value="0">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="drink_id" value="<?php print $list['drink_id']; ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="change">
                                </form>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                <?php }
                        }
                    } ?>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

const.php

```
<?php
$uploaddir = './drink_picture/';
$err_msg = [];
$err_msg2 = [];
$complete_msg = [];

define('DB_HOST',   ''); // データベースのホスト名又はIPアドレス
define('DB_USER',   '');  // MySQLのユーザ名
define('DB_PASSWD', '');    // MySQLのパスワード
define('DB_NAME',   '');    // データベース名

define('HTML_CHARACTER_SET', 'UTF-8');  // HTML文字エンコーディング
define('DB_CHARACTER_SET',   'UTF8');   // DB文字エンコーディング

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
```

ファイルパス指定
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: エラーメッセージの訳の意味は理解されていますか？またエラーメッセージで検索してみたりはしましたか？

Comment: 意味は理解しています。検索もしました。変数はちゃんと宣言してるのにどう直せばいいかわからない状況です。

Comment: 一枚目のエラーは「Undefined variable」ではなくて「Undefined index」です。そもそもエラーメッセージを読み間違えていませんか？

Comment: keitaro_soさんも指摘されているように、一枚目のエラーはvalidation_check関数内で未定義のインデックスを使用しているために出ています。insert_drink関数のようにissetを使ってやればどうなります？

Answer (score 1):

ひとつ目のスクリーンショットについては、定義されていないキーを参照しようとして警告になっています。たとえば、`$_POST` がまだ `'new_name'` をキーとする値を持っていないのに `$_POST['new_name']` を参照しようとして警告になっています。

`isset($_POST['new_name'])` とするなど、[`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) もしくは [`!empty()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) を使うことで、存在判定をしてから使うようにしてください。

ふたつ目のスクリーンショットについては、`insert_drink()` の定義中にてエラーが起こったときに各種変数が定義されていないので警告になっています。

エラー時は early return し、正常時の処理が実行されないように処理を書いてください。`$err_msg[]` にエラーメッセージを代入するだけでは処理は終わらず、そのまま下の方に処理が続行します。

### エラー原因の見つけ方

警告表示に出ているメッセージとバックトレースを注意深く読むのが大事です。

たとえば最初に出た警告の中から、この部分を見てみましょう。

[image]

この表示から、以下のことが分かります。

- `Undefined index` が検出されている。
- これは tool2.php の中で `validation_check()` を呼び出した中で起きている。
- 更に `validation_check()` の関数定義の中の、`if ($_POST['new_name'] === "") {` という行で起きている。（このことはメッセージに書かれている functions.php の 366 行目、という情報を元にファイルを読むと分かります。）

さて、`Undefined index` という警告がどんな意味なのか検索すると、これは配列に対して存在しないキーで参照しようとしたときに出るエラーだと分かります。ここでの index というのは和訳すると添え字、つまり配列のキーのことで、`$_POST['new_name']` と書いたときの `'new_name'` の部分です。

実際ページを開いた際にこの部分がどのように実行されるかを頭の中でプログラムを追いながら考えてみると、`<body>` を読み込む際にフォームを送るなどの処理より真っ先に `$err_msg = validation_check($link);` が実行されており、そのようなときに `$_POST['new_name']` は存在しないので、確かに警告に繋がりそうです。

これが単なる変数であれば、変数を参照するより先に定義しようという話になるのですが、`$_POST` はそういう変数ではありません。したがって `isset()` や `!empty()` を使って存在判定をしてから使おうという話になります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。参考にさせていただきます。